# Open Source Linux Acrobat Javascript Editor

Tags: javascript, linux, pdf, adobe, acrobat

Are there any OpenSource projects which will run in Linux for editing a PDF document, and specifically editing the Acrobat JavaScript within the PDF document?

Comment: What do you need this for? Are you trying to edit a PDF that was created via Adobe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution that exactly met your requirements. Hopefully, the following will provide some help.

1. **PDFedit** - http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html

   > PDFedit is a free open source pdf editor and a library for
   >   manipulating PDF documents, released under terms of GNU GPL version 2.
   >   It includes PDF manipulating library based on xpdf, GUI, set of
   >   command line tools and a pdf editor.

   **PS** The PDFedit documentation mentions scripting support but does not explicit mention Acrobat scripts.
2. **Multi-platform PDF Editors** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software#Editors
3. **Unix and Linux PDF Editors** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software#Editors_2
4. **The Acrobat JavaScript Console (Windows)** - http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/javascript_console

   > The Acrobat JavaScript Console window (a.k.a. the Console window) is
   >   one of the tools included in the Acrobat JavaScript Debugger. The
   >   Console window is by far the most useful tool in Adobe Acrobat for
   >   testing and debugging JavaScript code, but it is more than just a
   >   utility for testing code. It can also execute code snippets for
   >   automating tasks in Acrobat and analyzing documents. In this article,
   >   we’ll cover setting up and using this essential tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really desperate, you can open the .pdf file using a text editor. In all of the text you will find the field's Javascript, which you can edit and then save. It is a pain to do, but you can certainly make minor adjustments to the code in this way.

Be sure to make a copy of the original .pdf file as an archive before trying to edit it, of course.